How to get the video resolution from a File in Dart/Flutter?
I was using video_player to do the rest of the metadata extraction I need but I didn't find a way to get the resolution with this package.

VideoPlayerController is a ValueNotifier<VideoPlayerValue> and the VideoPlayerValue has a size property that reports the size of the video.
https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/f5a45177034bff79d7df07a85077218774aa4a80/packages/video_player/video_player/lib/video_player.dart#L42
You can add a listener to the VideoPlayerController and be notified when the value changes. Depending on the source, the size of the video can change too (for example if it's a HLS stream with multiple variants).

dependencies:
flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.4.1

import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/media_information.dart';

Future<String> getVideoResolution(String videoPath) async {
final FlutterFFprobe _flutterFFprobe = FlutterFFprobe();
MediaInformation mediaInformation;
try {
mediaInformation = await _flutterFFprobe.getMediaInformation(videoPath);
if (mediaInformation != null &&
    mediaInformation.getStreams() != null &&
    mediaInformation.getStreams().isNotEmpty) {
  // Assuming the first stream contains the video
  final videoStream = mediaInformation.getStreams()[0];
  if (videoStream != null && videoStream.getAllProperties() != null) {
    final width = videoStream.getAllProperties()['width'];
    final height = videoStream.getAllProperties()['height'];
    return '$width x $height';
      }
    }
   } catch (e) {
     print('Error getting video resolution: $e');
  }
  return 'Unknown';
 }

String resolution = await getVideoResolution('/path/to/your/video.mp4');
print('Video resolution: $resolution');

